# Using ellipsis with div and span in bootstrap panel title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I put the buttons in the same line as the text **"Nulla vitae quam a velit dictum tincidunt. Maecenas..."** ?

I am using this

```
style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"
```

so the line ends in the panel size. Without it, and if the text isn't big enough, the buttons and the text stay in the same line.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/4PHAE/**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
            <span>Nulla vitae quam a velit dictum tincidunt. Maecenas sed dapibus nunc.</span>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">?</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <p class="lead" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><small>Iten #1, Iten #2, Iten #3, Iten #4, Iten #5, Iten #6, Iten #7, </small></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the buttons outside the `.panel-heading` because it's the element that force the `overflow:hidden` and then give a property of `float` or `display:inline-block` to your button and text divs with fixed width.

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
        <span>Nulla vitae quam a velit dictum tincidunt. Maecenas sed dapibus nunc.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">?</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
}
.panel-heading {
  max-width:150px;
  float:left;
}
.btn-toolbar {
  width:50px;
  float:right;
}
```

Review this Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6ZpBL/2/**